# Most efficient way for LINQ query on InverseProperty in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, automapper

Assuming I've the following Entity Framework Code-First models:

```
public class Employee {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId ))]
  public Department Department { get; set; }

  public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
}

public class Manager {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId ))]
  public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department {
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty(nameof(Employee.Department))]
  public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty(nameof(Manager.Department))]
  public virtual ICollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

And the following DTO object:

```
public class MyDto {
  public int ManagerId { get; set; }
  public Employee NewestEmployee { get; set; }  
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to convert a list of managers to a list of DTO objects. AutoMapper configuration is like this:

```
CreateMap<Manager, MyDto>()
  .ForMember(
    m => m.NewestEmployee,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(
      manager =>
        manager.Department.Employees.OrderBy(employee => employee.EntryDate).FirstOrDefault()))
```

And called like this:

```
IEnumerable<Manager> managers = GetAllManagers();
var data = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyDto>>(managers);
```

While this works it makes individual SQL statement requests for each manager to the employee table. Is there a way to improve performance by having only one SQL query executed (either by changing something in the Entity Framework models or AutoMapper configuration)?

Comment: I think using [projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) will help - so that would be `var data = managers.ProjectTo<MyDto>().ToList()`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately using `ProjectTo` doesn't seems to change anything in my case. Also getting same amount of requests as with `Mapper.Map`.

Comment: Check this article, maybe it could help you: http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Comment: @PascalBerger `ProjectTo` must be combined with real `IQueryable<T>`. Use `var` keyword and make sure you don't convert managers to `IEnumerable` / `List`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. This can be my problem, just found some code which caches the IQueryable into an IEnumerable which would explain my behavior. Using ProjectTo seems to work otherwise as excpected.